# Is the permittivity of a dielectric medium measured by application of radio frequency of 1 KHz and a resonant circuit of 1KHz are same?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, capacitance, dielectric

I am working on a procedure in which I assess the dielectric constant of a medium by subjecting the dielectric medium to electromagnetic radiation of certain frequency (or the medium is subjected to a certain frequency of radio spectrum)[as discussed here](https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/00aps_undefined/RAC-0607-0019_1_5E.pdf) . On the other hand there is a study that does calculate the dielectric constant of the substance by placing it in a capacitor (assume parallel plate capacitor separated by distance d and filled with dielectric of target substance) of a resonant circuit having the alternating current source [similar to this](http://www.electrochemsci.org/papers/vol9/90703864.pdf). I want to know what is the difference between these two.

Comment: If you have made progress yourself on this, it's always okay to post an answer to your own question. Also, just curious, how your measurements turned out in [this experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451648/83380)?

Comment: @uhoh I discontinued this experiment and I started working in to find the glucose concentration using chiral effects. So just left it dormant for some time. I'll update you soon if i see any positive results.

Comment: Sounds good, glad to hear you are continuing your experiments!